# Script with ssh connection isn't working in crontab raspberry pi

Tags: bash, shell, cron, autostart

I have a script that does a ssh connection to a Ubuntu machine to get a file and store it on my raspberry pi. If I execute the script manually, in shell it works perfectly how I want it but in crontab -e it doesn't work. I also have another script in crontab that I also start with @reboot and this script works perfectly fine on reboot.
I assume that the script is getting executed without the network being up but I don't know how to work around it.

This is my crontab -e :

```
@reboot bash /home/pi/skript/conf.sh
@reboot node /home/pi/node/buttonled.js
```

and this my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=`(ssh davy@192.168.0.15 ls -t /home/davy/rundgaenge | head -1)` 2>/home/pi/skriptfehlermeldung.txt
scp davy@192.168.0.15:/home/davy/rundgaenge/$file /home/pi/rundgangConf/
```

Comment: You [should not use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and there are various other common issues here which http://shellcheck.net/ can diagnose. Maybe try that before asking for human assistance.

Comment: The parentheses in the subshell are unnecessary and somewhat distracting; I thought they were a syntax error at first.

Comment: well the script does work from the command line...

Comment: Using `.sh` in the name of a `node` script is so odd it's tempting to say it's wrong.

Comment: oh yeah you're right I actually have it as .js but I typed it wrong my fault, sorry

Comment: I spellchecked my script on shellcheck.net with $() and now it says that it detects no issues so I would say that my script is working fine..

Comment: What does your `skriptfehlermeldung.txt` say?

Comment: You should also have received a warning for the [missing quotes](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) but if you fixed that too, all good. (The extra parentheses are still unnecessary and slightly inefficient.)

Comment: My uninformed guess is that the network is fine but `cron` lacks access tn the `ssh` key.

Comment: Does cron email you any job output? If not, you could try adding something like this to the top of your script: `exec 1>>/var/tmp/script.log 2>&1; date; set -x;` and see what it produces